# How to keep previous status of input with `change` event of them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two radio button inputs and when one of them is clicked, it will be checked and alerts the user if he or she is going to submit the inputs. Any of them could be pre-checked depending on user's log history.

The problem is this: I want to revert the checked status of radio inputs when the user clicks *cancel* button of the alert dialog.

It will be easy to implement this if the event `change` passes pre-change status and post-change status, but it seems it does not.

Is there any way to record previous status of inputs within `change` event of them?

Comment: Can include `html` , `js`  at Question ?

Comment: Yes! I changed my question

Comment: You can listen to `mouseup` instead.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts is `mouseup` fired before the `change` event?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts The mouse is not the only way to change the radios. It can be done with the keyboard too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store a reference to the `RadioNodeList` of the radios, and also store the current value.

When the `change` event listener is fired, you can update the stored value, or undo the change by assigned the old value as the `value` property.

This will work, assuming all the radios have different values.

```js
var form = document.forms[0],
    els = form.elements.myradio,
    val = els.value;
form.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  if(confirm('Do you want to change?'))
    val = els.value; // Update the value
  else
    els.value = val; // Undo (assign the old value)
});
```

```html
<form>
  <label><input type="radio" name="myradio" value="1" checked />1</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="myradio" value="2" />2</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="myradio" value="3" />3</label>
</form>
```